# Possible to remove my app from settings app?

Tags: iphone, preferences, settings.bundle

Previous versions of my app have used the Settings.bundle method to have some user preferences managed in the (external) settings app. I've done away with that now, but I'd like to be able to de-register my application so that old users who upgrade don't have a useless entry in their settings app. Any idea if this is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Turns out that after I delete my Settings.bundle and upgrade a previously-installed version of my app, it *does* get removed from the preferences app. The trick is that unless you do a "Clean", you won't see this behavior in the simulator, for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delete the Settings.bundle file and Move to Trash, Clean All Targets, Then Build and Go.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work any more due to a bug in iOS 6, maybe even iOS 5. The bundle will not be removed from the Settings.app any more, even if no settings bundle is shipped with the app.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the Settings.bundle?